# need help switching pages

Tags: javascript, html

i need help with my function. i have all my variables.

```js
var swith = document.getElementById("sub");
var one = document.getElementById("rule");
var two = document.getElementById("cool");
var three = document.getElementById("fool");

Function cool() {
 if(swith,one) window.location.replace("app.html");
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>question?</title>
<link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body id="QA"> 
<select id="much">
<option id="rule">0-10,000</option>
<option id="cool">25,00-50,000</option>
<option id="fool">75,000-100,000</option>
<input type="submit" id="sub">
<script src="app.js"></script>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

i think i missed something important. but google stated "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. `function ` not `Function `

Answer (score 1):

Try lower case `f` for `Function` eg:

```
function cool() {
    if(swith,one) window.location.replace("app.html");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Function with a capital "F" is a [function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) in javascript. 
You should be using the regular function expression.

Instead of adding id attributes to options, I suggest adding a value attribute and on submit of the containing form, you carry out your logic for submission.

I have attached a raw snippet which you could expand and modify to suit your needs. This snippet submission will not work on this site due to sandboxing of form submission.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById("TestForm").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
    
      if (this.value === "rule") {
         document.location.replace('app.html');
      }
  },false);
  
 
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>question?</title>
</head>

<body id="QA">
  <form id="TestForm" name="TestForm" action="#">
  <select id="much">
    <option value="rule">0-10,000</option>
    <option value="cool">25,00-50,000</option>
    <option value="fool">75,000-100,000</option>
  </select>
    <input type=submit value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```